# How to debug "No database selected" error using MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I face  error

> Error: INSERT INTO biodata('fname', 'lname', 'email', 'phone', 'message') VALUES('syed', 'Masroor', 'masroor_toori@yahoo.com', '0215586484', 'dhflhdfvh',)
>   No database selected

SQL query:

[image: SQL query]

I have made database which is here:

[image: DataBase]

Comment: Post the code here not images of it please

Comment: You need to select your database using PHP code before you execute your SQL syntax, not in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: You have one extra comma at the end in query.

Comment: Please do still remove the image of the code from your question - this should be ordinary text. If you want to show the structure of your table, please just use the text from `SHOW CREATE TABLE biodata;` rather than an image of phpMyAdmin. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect your db connection properly

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('db_name', $link);

Answer (score 0):

i think that the extra , at the end the values causes this problem

INSERT INTO biodata('fname', 'lname', 'email', 'phone', 'message') VALUES('syed', 'Masroor', 'masroor_toori@yahoo.com', '0215586484', 'dhflhdfvh'**,**)